# Calculating a crazy trigonometric integral

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

What is the fastest and best way to do this crAZy integral? 
$$ \int\frac{1-\tan^4\theta d\theta}{\tan^{\frac{9}{6}}\theta(\sec^2 \theta+\tan\theta)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\tan^{\frac{10}{6}}\theta (\sec^2 \theta+ \tan\theta)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$

I tried substituting:

$ \tan x = t$

but that comes out to something more ugly..

Comment: 1. Please avoid post titles that consists entirely of a formula. 2.Please use the trig function macros in MathJax.

Comment: trig function macros? what are those

Comment: The title is literally 150 words I can not put text

Comment: `\tan` to get $\tan$ instead of $tan$; `\sec`, `\sin`, `\cos`.

Comment: Which suggests you should try something else than a big formula. Also, you should include the entirety of your question in the body, not just in the title. In short, this was a mess.

Comment: the reason I put integral there is that people can find the question easily if they search

Comment: thank you for your patience :)

Comment: It doesn't help search any faster than putting in the body of the question. And there are reasons why having a title that consists entirely of mathjax code is unadvisable.

Comment: @DDD4C4U it is still unclear to me what the $1/2$ and $1/3$ exponents in the denominator are referring to.

Comment: Hint 1: does $1- \tan^4\theta$ factorise?
Hint 2: can the result be used with the substitution $u = \tan\theta$ ?

Comment: Putting $z=\tan(x)$ returned
$$
\int \frac{1-z^2}{\sqrt{z^2+z+1} z^{3/2}+\sqrt[3]{z^2+z+1} z^{5/3}} \, dz;
$$Mathematica couldn't handle that (or the original). I'm beginning to think this is hopeless.

Comment: Source of the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ \int\frac{(1-\tan^4\theta) d\theta}{\tan^{\frac{9}{6}}\theta(\sec^2 \theta+\tan\theta)^{\frac{1}{2}}+\tan^{\frac{10}{6}}\theta (\sec^2 \theta+ \tan\theta)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$

$$ \rightarrow \int \frac{ \sec^2 \theta (1- \tan^2 \theta) d\theta}{  \tan^{\frac{3}{2}} \theta \left[\sec^2 \theta + \tan \theta \right]^{\frac{1}{2}} + \tan^{ \frac{5}{3} } \theta  \left[\sec^2 \theta + \tan \theta \right]^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$

$$ \rightarrow \int \frac{ \sec^2 \theta (1- \tan^2 \theta) d\theta}{ \tan^2 \theta \left[ ( \frac{\sec^2 \theta}{\tan \theta} +1 )^{\frac{1}{2}}  +  ( \frac{\sec^2 \theta}{\tan \theta} +1 )^{\frac{1}{3}}  \right]}$$

$$  k=  \frac{\sec^2 \theta}{\tan \theta} +1 $$

$$ dk = - \frac{ \sec^2 \theta (1- \tan^2 \theta)}{ \tan^2 \theta} d\theta$$

$$ \int \rightarrow -\frac{dk}{ k^{\frac{1}{2}} + k^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$

$$k^{\frac{1}{6} } = y$$

$$ dk = 6y^5 dy$$

$$ \rightarrow \int \frac{ - 6 y^5 dy}{y^3 + y^2}$$

$$=-2y^3 +3y^2-6y +6log(y+1) +C$$

And sub back $$ y= \left( \frac{\sec^2 \theta +1}{ \tan \theta} \right)^6$$